# How to check if cell is null by column name in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to build a stored procedure in SQL.

I have the following syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAllCitizens]
    @NoInfo as nvarchar(50) = "No contact information inserted."
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF ctznPhone != null
        BEGIN
            SELECT ctznTz, ctznLname, ctznFname, ctznPhone
            FROM tblCitizens
            Where ctznLivestat=1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF ctznEml != null
                BEGIN
                SELECT ctznTz, ctznLname, ctznFname, ctznEml
                FROM tblCitizens
                Where ctznLivestat=1
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SELECT ctznTz, ctznLname, ctznFname, @NoInfo
                    FROM tblCitizens
                    Where ctznLivestat=1
                END
        END
END
```

How do I tell the procedure in which table the columns `ctznPhone` and `ctznEml` are?

I have tried `dbo.tablename.columname` and various attempts with `()` and `[]` but it doesn't seem to work.

Eventually, this procedure will be called upon by a C# datareader.
What I am trying to do is build a procedure that, when called upon, will return the selected cells from a row, depending on the information in specific cells:

- If `ctznPhone` is not null, then I want to get it.
- If it's null, I want to get `ctznEml` instead.
- If THAT's null as well, I want to get back a message that no contact information is available (a string which I have placed in `@NoInfo`).

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: COALESCE is what you want but you should also know, `!= null` is wrong, you want `is not null` or `is null` these are both urinary operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

> **COALESCE ( expression [ ,...n ] )**
>
> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAllCitizens]
    @NoInfo as nvarchar(50) = "No contact information inserted."
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT ctznTz, ctznLname, ctznFname,
         COALESCE(ctznPhone, ctznEml, @NoInfo) AS contactInfo
  FROM tblCitizens
  WHERE ctznLivestat=1;

END
```

Comment: What is the "AS contactInfo"? Is that a made up name under which this information will return?

Comment: @NimrodYanai Yes, It is a column alias for expression.

Comment: That's fantastic!
I don't know why our teacher wanted us to use IIF when this COALESCE is so much more accurate for our needs...